# Network challenge - trusted domains

Tags: .net, iis, asp-classic, active-directory, intranet

Within my organization, I have two domains **A** and **B**. There is a Classic ASP web intranet application hosted in an IIS server in **Domain B** (Windows Authentication enabled, all other authentication modes disabled). As for as I know, **A** and **B** is in a **Domain Trust** relationship.

The problem here is, when users logged in to **Domain A** try to access the web application mentioned above, it prompts for the **Domain B** user id and password. My understanding is that since both domains are trusted, **Domain A** users should also be able to access the web application. Please suggest any possible reasons for this behavior.